# Make group by having count(*) with django orm

Tags: django, django-orm

With following model:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(
        unique=True,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )


class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name='reservations',
        verbose_name=_('Utilisateur'),
    )
    day = models.ForeignKey(
        Day,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name='reservations',
    )
```

To get days ids where number of reservations is lower or equal 5 i do:

```
SELECT day_id
FROM meal_reservation
GROUP BY day_id
HAVING count(*) <= 5
```

But how to do it with Django ORM ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Read the docs about the combination of using [values+annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#values), this is what you need:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Reservation.objects.values('day').annotate(cnt=Count('id')).filter(cnt__lte=5)
```

Comment: Thank's, i was trying without .values

Comment: gotta do `from django.db.models import Count `